# Recursive usage of slots in vue3/typescript/sfc

Tags: typescript, vue.js, vuejs3, vue-sfc

I'm trying to implement simple treeview using vue3 and typescript

```
npm init vue@latest // when asks about typescript support - say yes, and just press Enter on all other questions
cd '.\vue-project\'
```

add file TreeNode.vue

```
<template>
  <div>
    <div>
      <slot :item="item" />
    </div>
    <div style="margin-left: 10px" v-for="(child, index) in item.children" :key="index">
      <TreeNode :item="child">
        <template v-slot="{item}">
          <slot :item="item" />
        </template>
      </TreeNode>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>

<script setup lang="ts">  
  const props = defineProps<{ item: Item }>()
</script>

<script lang="ts">
  export type Item = {
    name: string
    children: Array<Item>
  }
</script>
```

when run
`npm run type-check`

and got error:

```
src/components/TreeNode.vue:8:19 - error TS2615: Type of property 'default' circularly references itself in mapped type '{ [K in keyof (Readonly<InternalSlots> & { default: (_: any) => any; })]-?: (Readonly<InternalSlots> & { default: (_: any) => any; })[K] extends ((obj: infer O) => any) | undefined ? O : any; }'.

8         <template v-slot="{item}">
```

Any idea how to avoid this error  ??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As I said in the comments, you code works perfectly fine ([it renders](https://sfc.vuejs.org/#eNqNU8Fu2zAM/RVCl7RAbG9XIyvQ4y7DDrvNO7g27aq1JYGSswWB/32UVNlxgnXNRaL4+EzyvZzFozH5cUJRioNtSBoHFt1kHiolR6PJwQ9C/KZbhI70CLu8SA++bFepRivrQDocv5wrBaDqEctdo7laoXJ2t/evzbMcWkJV/vQRQID6X4R3msYI9L8VvMASUCozMWd6nvc3CKpbqd8DWBywcSviV7zN/uA7n5U6FHEZvAYOeDYz1A595A7LQsowdCX8UQlOepoFDMfMDtpx/hy2wx9IGEa18gjWnQbk/FPdvPakJ9VmjR40lUDYXoABMjhHktyPAHPoNfAUTJS+XGz7XITi8CIn9iIqm421yV+sVqx9WBJPEhK2EmUSqBKsso8r8eycsWVR2K7x0r/YXFNf8C2nSTk5Yo52zJ5I/7ZITFyJN0EDR8GPR6SMZW2RkN7jvILe8HpaXsHMo1ya8drDMNSq5/36gXgHLXZS4XfSxh7iNkv4GoR5uLu/lvyNZ8sglUPq6gZj3Wp3lpKk6jdGh0ei+nTwSC7ldv/pqWiHpOJ65cA76MpnUCx6b6vYcPw3Ytxd6GEPkkf+c89HtE7qjCnKVzx5Qg/gMBlxrKmXKhuwcyV8/mQ4t7ZyY/vAt7Hpx7z/38FuzJyeLgy9XUC6barE/BezbZTp)). Error is from TS. My guess is it's some minor typing problem in Vue (or maybe a limitation of TS)

I was able to get rid of the problem using [dynamic slot names](https://vuejs.org/guide/components/slots.html#dynamic-slot-names) - more dynamic code makes it impossible to statically analyze the types, so TS stops complaining

`TreeNode.vue`

```js
<script setup lang="ts">
const props = defineProps<{ item: Item }>();
</script>

<script lang="ts">
export type Item = {
  name: string;
  children?: Array<Item>;
};

const slotName = 'default';
</script>

<template>
  <div>
    <div>
      <slot :item="props.item" />
    </div>
    <div
      v-for="(child, index) in props.item.children"
      :key="index"
      style="margin-left: 10px"
    >
      <TreeNode :item="child">
        <template #[slotName]="{ item }: { item: Item }">
          <slot :item="item" />
        </template>
      </TreeNode>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>
```

[Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/vitejs-vite-hjrfas?file=src/components/TreeNode.vue) - just open another terminal and run `npm run check`

Answer (score 1):

No need to two slots the second one is enough without using `default` slot template, In the first slot you should render the content of the current node

```html
<script setup lang="ts">
defineProps<{ item: Item }>()
</script>

<script lang="ts">
interface Item {
  name: string
  children: Array<Item>
}
</script>

<template>
  <div>
    <div>
      {{ item.name }}
    </div>
    <div v-for="(child, index) in item.children" :key="index" style="margin-left: 10px">
      <TreeNode :item="child">
        <slot :item="item" />
      </TreeNode>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>
```

**[LIVE DEMO](https://sfc.vuejs.org/#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)**

Answer (score 0):

I had an idea, and it worked.

```
<script setup lang="ts">
    const p = (item: any) => item
</script>
<template>
    ... Some vue template markup here
    <template v-if="$slots.actionCol" #actionCol="slotProps">
        <slot name="actionCol" v-bind="p(slotProps)" />
    </template>
</template>
```